# Invoke vs get on ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream

Premise: I'm not very familiar with concurrency.

Take a look at this code:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestSync {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intArray = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 500).boxed().toList();

        System.out.println("Element size: " + intArray.size());
        
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(intArray.size());
        ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(50);
        
        customThreadPool.submit( () -> {
            intArray.parallelStream().forEach(sp -> {
                System.out.println("Remaining int: " + i.decrementAndGet());
            });
        }).invoke();
        customThreadPool.shutdown();
    }

}
```

The related output is:

```
Element size: 500
Remaining int: 499
Remaining int: 498
Remaining int: 497
Remaining int: 495
Remaining int: 494
Remaining int: 493
Remaining int: 492
Remaining int: 491
Remaining int: 490
Remaining int: 489
Remaining int: 488
Remaining int: 487
....
Remaining int: -74
Remaining int: -75
Remaining int: -66
Remaining int: -77
Remaining int: -78
Remaining int: -79
Remaining int: -80
Remaining int: -81
Remaining int: -82
Remaining int: -83
...
```

If I replace the `invoke()` with `get()`, negative numbers will never appear.

Can some one help me to understand the difference between `invoke()` and `get()`?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `invoke()` on the ForkJoinTask you force it to execute.
But before you already submitted it for execution in the pool, so you execute it twice.

Performing `get()` will wait for the task (that was already submitted to the pool) to complete and return the result.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. So I think that the good approce if I use a ForkJoinPool is to use the `get()` method. In my real case I'm trying to use it in a quarkus application; using the `get` method I get this error: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigFactory: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.QuarkusConfigFactory not a subtype`. Have you ever had a similar problem?